# Symmetry action on spin liquid ansatz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, second-quantization, spin-models

In mean-field parton theory of Heisenberg model, the hamiltonian can be written as
$$H_{MF} = \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} Tr(\psi_i^\dagger U_{ij} \psi_j) + \sum_i Tr(\psi_i^\dagger (\vec{a}_i\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \psi_i)$$

where $\psi = \begin{pmatrix}
c_{i, \uparrow} & c_{i, \downarrow}\\
c_{i, \uparrow}^\dagger & - c_{i, \uparrow}^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}$, and $U_{ij} = \langle \psi_i \psi_j^\dagger\rangle$ and $\vec{a}_i$ is the (mean-field) Lagrange multiplier for single occupancy constraint. It seems common to call $\{U_{ij}, \vec{a}_i\}$ an mean field **ansatz**, which essentially specify the hopping/pairing amplitudes of the quadratic hamiltonian. (For simplicity, I'll leave out $\vec{a}$ in the following.)

***My confusion:***

when we transform the system, say act rotation operator $R$ on the system, mathematically this means

$$H_{MF} \rightarrow H_{MF}^{'} = R H_{MF} R^-$$

and so we should transform the **ansatz and operator $\psi$**:

$$U_{ij} \rightarrow U_{R(i) R(j)}\\
\psi_i \rightarrow \psi_{R(i)}$$

However, in the context of projective symmetry group (PSG), we only **transform the ansatz and leave the operator alone**! Rather than transforming the whole hamiltonian, we only symmetry transforms the ansatz, and find a gauge transformation to bring the ansatz back. I think there is something simple I'm missing here.